# Execution failed for task ':alert:generateDebugRFile'

Tags: android, flutter, build

I reset my laptop and I'm getting this error when compiling my flutter application

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':alert:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':alert:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-5e9e0e0aa8be4ff69facadd706b713f0bb54d5b3.
     Required by:
         project :alert
      > Skipped due to earlier error
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Run in sequence `flutter clean`, then `flutter pub get` and then try again.

Comment: Reinstalled android sdk and flutter, it worked. Thanks